# .npz file not saving what's inside

Tags: python-3.x, numpy

I was trying to build a face recognition cnn with numpy and encountered this problem when trying to access npz file with different folders of images inside, i've use code

```
image = "D:\project\Images"
np.savez("Test_Images.npz", image)
data = np.load('Test_Images.npz')

print (data.file)
```

when I tried to use npz viewer it also shows me that theres no arrays or files inside, what is wrong with the code? Am I missing something?

I've tried changing the folders inside to zip files but still didn't save, also tried just use

```
np.load("path/to/folder")
```

but it just causes permission error

Comment: more information needed, includes, what the file hierarchy is, etc.

Answer (score 1):

`np.savez` is not intended to store the contents of a folder specified by a string. The positional arguments of [`np.savez`](https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.savez.html) after the first are *arrays* to be saved. You would need to load the images as arrays (e.g. with [imageio](https://imageio.readthedocs.io/en/stable/)) and use `np.savez` to save those arrays.

Answer (score 1):

Lets run your code in an `ipython` session:

```
In [1]: import numpy as np    
In [2]: image = "D:\project\Images"
   ...: np.savez("Test_Images.npz", image)
   ...: data = np.load('Test_Images.npz')
```

So what is `data`?

```
In [3]: data
Out[3]: <numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile at 0x1d9443b74f0>
```

It's a dict like object, so takes a `keys` method:

```
In [4]: data.keys()
Out[4]: KeysView(<numpy.lib.npyio.NpzFile object at 0x000001D9443B74F0>)
```

For which we need to use `list` to see what's what:

```
In [5]: list(data.keys())
Out[5]: ['arr_0']
```

That means, it's a `zip` archive with one file, which we can load as a `dict` access:

```
In [6]: data['arr_0']
Out[6]: array('D:\\project\\Images', dtype='<U17')
```

So that file contains an array with one string element, which we can extract with:

```
In [7]: data['arr_0'].item()
Out[7]: 'D:\\project\\Images'
```

`savez` saved the string `image` - inside an array inside an archived file.  That's all!

### edit

If I copy that `npz` file to `test.zip`, I can open it in the windows file viewer, which tells me it contains one file

```
arr_0.npy
```

which if I open with windows notebook is:

```
“NUMPY v {'descr': '<U17', 'fortran_order': False, 'shape': (), }                                                             
D   :   \   p   r   o   j   e   c   t   \   I   m   a   g   e   s
```